# Dual monitor - launcher placement issue

Tags: unity, launcher, multiple-monitors

I have a HP elitebook 8460p with a 2nd hdmi display to the left of the laptop; OS Ubuntu 16.04, i5vpro-2520M, 8gb ddr3 ram, 250gb ssd, running prop intel driver set installed.

What I want is my primary display to be the laptop display, with my launcher panel showing on the primary display.  What is happening is my primary display sets to the laptop but my launcher panel always throws to the left monitor when I set the monitor arrangement in display control panel as described above.

1. Switching the position in display control panel fixes it but then I have to go to the right "around the world" to reach my left monitor, not a solution.
2. With position settings set to external-left laptop-right, going to panel settings and changing from auto to lock it to laptop display is not effective because they're not labeled by display name but by "monitor 1" and "monitor 2", and with position settings like this my laptop display becomes "monitor 2".  If I now disconnect the laptop (making laptop display "monitor 1" now) and move somewhere then my panel launcher is now locked to the now unconnected "monitor 2" and is not visible.

I know it's possible to do this because just a month ago I was running ubuntu 16.04 in this same configuration successfully with auto panel placement putting my panel in correct display whether I'm connected at my desk or disconnected and mobile.  I decided to do a clean installation when I got a new SSD and now I cannot get it back to behaving the way I'd expect it to.

Because of my desk layout I don't really have an option to move it around differently.  I'm going to temporarily move it physically to correct what appears to be a software issue (though this could just as easily be a user issue, but so many others having similar issues).

xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected primary 1366x768+1920+144 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1366x768      60.00*+  40.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1400x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      74.98    59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings/Displays, and toggle the setting circled below, to the desired screen.

[image]